# Submenu not displaying properly when i fectch data from database in Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Good day all I wanted to create a dynamic menu with submenu populating the menus from database. I created two tables mainmenu which related to submenu.

The mainmenu gets populated and is didplayed properly but the submenu is populated but does not dropdown properly, the submenu stays ontop of each other.

However if I manually code both mainmenu and submenu both work fine. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time.

**What I Wanted**
[image]
**What I am Getting**
[image]

My Code - Django Template

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse sub-menu-bar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                {% for item in mainmenu %}
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{{ item.menulink }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                                    {% for submenu in item.submenu.all %}
                                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="{{ submenu.menulink }}">{{ submenu.name }}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endfor%}
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

**My Custom Context Processor**

```
from setup.models import Setup, Mainmenu, Submenu

def setup(request):
    setup = Setup.objects.first()
    return {'organisation': setup}

def mainmenu(request):
    mainmenu = Mainmenu.objects.order_by("order").filter(menutype="main")
    return {'mainmenu': mainmenu}

def submenu(request):
    submenu = Submenu.objects.order_by("order").filter(menutype="submenu")
    return {'submenu': submenu}`

 - My Database Table

 

class Mainmenu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Menu Name"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    menulink = models.CharField(_("Menu Link"), max_length=512, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Enter menu link like this, <code>https://uidc.com.ng/page/display/about-us/</code>")
    order = models.CharField(_("Menu Order"), max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.CharField(_("Is Active"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    menutype = models.CharField(_("Menu Type"), max_length=256)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    datecreated = models.DateField(_("Date Created"), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Mainmenu")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Mainmenus")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Submenu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Submenu Name"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    mainmenu = models.ForeignKey(
        Mainmenu, verbose_name=_("Main Menu"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="submenu"
    )
    menulink = models.CharField(_("Submenu Link"), max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.CharField(_("Submenu Order"), max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.CharField(_("Is Active"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    menutype = models.CharField(_("Submenu Type"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    datecreated = models.DateField(_("Date Created"), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Submenu")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Submenus")
```

Comment: I believe the error is `{% for mainmenu in mainmenu %}` which is like `{% for X in X %}` which makes no sense.  Try doing `{% for item in mainmenu %}` then replace `{{ mainmenu.menulink }}` with `{{ item.menulink }}` etc...

Comment: @raphael thanks for taking time to look at my code. I have made the changes as you suggested but the results remain the same though my code now make more sense. Is there a change I have to make in the submenu code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone I found my error my code is now working fine. I placed the iteration of the submenu in the wrong place, that is covering the unoderlist `<ul>` tag where as it should have covered only the list `<li>` tag. So it is an HTML issue.

See the code that worked below. Thanks everyone.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse sub-menu-bar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    {% for item in mainmenu %}
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a href="{{ item.menulink }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                                {% for submenu in item.submenu.all %}
                                                <li><a href="{{ submenu.menulink }}">{{ submenu.name }}</a></li>
                                                {% endfor%}
                                            </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```